# Logback SyslogAppender stacktrace logging prefix

Tags: java, logback, syslog

We have recently switched from Log4J to Logback. Logging seems to work well except stack traces in SyslogAppender. They are prefixed just like remaining log messages.

Is there any way how to disable this prefix and ensure they will be printed just like in Log4J SyslogAppender? Thanks in advance.

Current behavior:

```
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name 2012-04-02T12:31:08.418+0200 ajp-bio-8009-exec-7 com.gooddata.exception.servlet.HttpExceptionTranslator ERROR: Processing client_request=/gdcwebapp/gdc/projects/FoodMartDemo/groups/everyone status=FAILED errorCode=gdc.usergroups.default_group_modification errorDescription="Attempt to modify default group (everyone)" exceptionId=abc37cf0-9c56-4e68-a4a7-2111ca823fd4 component=webapp request_id=cAWvICOaKVFF1VvI userId=1 projectId=FoodMartDemo nodeId=nodeOne nodeId=nodeOne, requestId=cAWvICOaKVFF1VvI, userId=1, projectId=FoodMartDemo
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name #011at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
```

Desired behavior:

```
Apr 02 12:31:08 host.name 2012-04-02T12:31:08.418+0200 ajp-bio-8009-exec-7 com.gooddata.exception.servlet.HttpExceptionTranslator ERROR: Processing client_request=/gdcwebapp/gdc/projects/FoodMartDemo/groups/everyone status=FAILED errorCode=gdc.usergroups.default_group_modification errorDescription="Attempt to modify default group (everyone)" exceptionId=abc37cf0-9c56-4e68-a4a7-2111ca823fd4 component=webapp request_id=cAWvICOaKVFF1VvI userId=1 projectId=FoodMartDemo nodeId=nodeOne nodeId=nodeOne, requestId=cAWvICOaKVFF1VvI, userId=1, projectId=FoodMartDemo
                          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
                          at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
                          at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
                          at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
                          at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
                          at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
                          at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
                          at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
```

Current logback.xml for SyslogAppender:

```xml
  <appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <facility>local2</facility>
    <syslogHost>localhost</syslogHost>
    <suffixPattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %t %c %p: %m component=webapp request_id=%X{requestId} userId=%X{userId} projectId=%X{projectId} nodeId=%X{nodeId} %X%n</suffixPattern>
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be able to fix this by setting the throwableExcluded parameter to true and specifying the exception in the suffix pattern.

```
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost>localhost</syslogHost>
    <facility>LOCAL7</facility>
    <throwableExcluded>true</throwableExcluded>
    <suffixPattern>%d{ISO8601} %p %t %c{0}.%M - %m%n%xException</suffixPattern>
</appender>
```

Depending on the syslog server you use, you might need to turn off control character escaping in order for the text to render properly. e.g. `$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off` for rsyslog v5

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution was proposed in logback mailing list (http://old.nabble.com/SyslogAppender-stacktrace-logging-prefix-td33555063.html), one of possible solutions is here: http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-327

Answer (score 0):

Logback's Syslog Appender is not handling this right. 
You would have to write your own. It can be based on original one. Basically the problem is over here:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(stackTracePrefix).append(step);
      sw.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
      sw.flush();
```

When you are flushing, it sends new message to syslog. If you want to avoid it, you would have to flush only after whole stack.